# How can I override the CXF services list URL?

Tags: cxf, talend, apache-karaf

My webservice has an REST endpoint URL like /myapp/admin/services. If I set `org.apache.cxf.servlet.hide-service-list-page=false` then my URL is hijacked by the CXF services list. This happens because the listings URL is *relative* in org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.

OK, fine, so I shouldn't have used the phrase "services" in my URL structure. Mea culpa. But now how do I fix this? I'd like to override the "/services" default in ServletController. I just need my container to invoke setServiceListRelativePath() on that class, but I can't figure out how. I imagine there's some magic Spring snippet to do this?

If it matters, I'm using CXF as bundled in the Talend Service Factory.

Comment: D'oh, I found it right after posting this question.  "servletConfig.getInitParameter("service-list-path")"

Comment: Under Karaf or TSF, the solution is to add the following to etc/org.apache.cxf.osgi.cfg: "org.apache.cxf.servlet.service-list-path=/desired/path"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(turning my comment above into an answer, and modernizing since TSF no longer exists)

Under Karaf, add the following to etc/org.apache.cxf.osgi.cfg: "org.apache.cxf.servlet.service-list-path=/desired/path"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your **web.xml** to override the CXF service list path

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>service-list-path</param-name>
  <param-value>/*</param-value>
</init-param>
```